# Pyspark DataFrame select rows with distinct values, and rows with non-distinct values

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Suppose I have a pyspark DataFrame (DF):

```
-----------------------------
record_id | foo | bar
-----------------------------
1 | random text | random text
2 | random text | random text
3 | random text | random text
1 | random text | random text
2 | random text | random text
-----------------------------
```

My end goal is to write these rows to MySQL with `.write.jdbc()`, which I've been doing successfully.  But now, before doing so, adding a new column `unique` based on the uniqueness of the `record_id` column.

I've made a bit of progress identifying unique `record_id`'s with something similar:

```
df.select('record_id').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0])
```

But unlike Panda's DataFrames, I don't believe this has an index I can reuse, it appears to just be the values.  I'm still fairly new to Spark/Pyspark.

Would it make sense to try and figure out the following workflow?

1. Identify rows with distinct `record_id`, and write to MySQL
2. Then, identify the remaining rows, and write to MySQL

Or would it be possible to alter the original DF, adding a new column `unique` based on some chained commands?  Something like the following, which I could then write to MySQL wholesale:

```
----------------------------------
record_id | foo | bar | unique 
----------------------------------
1 | random text | random text | 0
2 | random text | random text | 0
3 | random text | random text | 1 # where 1 for boolean True
1 | random text | random text | 0
2 | random text | random text | 0
----------------------------------
```

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the number of rows *partitionBy* record_id, if the record_id has only one row, mark it as *unique*:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("unique", (F.count("record_id").over(Window.partitionBy("record_id")) == 1).cast('integer')).show()
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
|record_id|        foo|        bar|unique|
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
|        3|random text|random text|     1|
|        1|random text|random text|     0|
|        1|random text|random text|     0|
|        2|random text|random text|     0|
|        2|random text|random text|     0|
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+
```